# Estimating the functional form of the slowly time-varying variance of a Gaussian process

Tags: estimation, nonparametric, standard-deviation

Consider the following simple set-up. In the interval $[0, 1]$ we are observing the realizations of independent normally distributed random variables at times $t_1,\ldots, t_N$. The r.v. $X(t)$ has mean 0 and standard deviation $\sigma(t)$, where all is known about $\sigma(\cdot)$ is that it is smooth, say at least differentiable. The goal is to estimate $\sigma$ so that the expected loss function (left to the reader to choose) is minimized.

I can think of many practical approaches, e.g. using kernels or approximating in a given basis, or penalizing the MLE; but is there any published literature on this simple problem? If not, what formal approach would you take?

Comment: At first blush, to get something meaningful, I think you will need to put further restrictions of the function $\sigma$. Differentiability is not much of a constraint, and the function can be essentially arbitrarily wild. (Can you construct a differentiable function $\sigma$ such that $|\sigma(t_i)| > B$ for all $t_i$ and any fixed $B$? Alternatively, think about the implications of [Stone--Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) to the problem as stated.)

Comment: My comment doesn't make quite as much sense as it should due to a typo. It should read "...such that $|\sigma'(t_i)| > B$ for all $t_i$...". (That is, we can make the derivative arbitrarily large.) Sorry about that.

Comment: I am open to let responders choose the family of functions and even the loss function.

Comment: Sounds good. My (minor) point was only that differentiability was not a very strong constraint at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functional data analysis, people often use penalties of the form

$$ \int_{D} [f^{(m)}(x)]^{2} dx $$

to ensure that an estimate of $f$ is smooth. Here $D$ is the domain of the function and $f^{(m)}(x)$ is the $m$'th derivative of $f$. In my own research I've found $m = 2$ to be useful. In your case the log-likelihood is

$$ -\frac{1}{2} \left( 2 \sum_{i=1}^{N} \log \big( \sigma(t_{i}) \big) + \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{x_{i}^{2}}{\sigma^{2}(t_{i})} \right) $$

An estimator that minimizes

$$ 
\left( 2 \sum_{i=1}^{N} \log \big( \sigma(t_{i}) \big) + \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{x_{i}^{2}}{\sigma^{2}(t_{i})} \right) + \lambda \int_{0}^{\infty} [\sigma^{(2)}(t)]^{2} dt $$

(or, equivalently, maximizes the penalized log likelihood) for an appropriately chosen tuning parameter, $\lambda$, will be smooth. This is a differentiable (on the interior of the parameter space) objective function of $\sigma(t_{1}), ..., \sigma(t_{K})$ (where $K$ is the number of unique time points) so it can be optimized using some standard approaches. Although, the potential non-convexity of the objective function could make starting values crucial for any optimization algorithm.

I've found that choosing $\lambda$ based on some model selection criteria such as AIC performs pretty well although there are many other potential choices. If you're going to go that route, the effective number of parameters in the model (which is required to calculate AIC) can be tricky to determine. As $\lambda \rightarrow 0$, you have the non-parametric MLE, so the number of parameters is equal to the number of unique times observed. As $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$, you have a perfectly linear fit (since the penalty will be 0 only when $\sigma(t)$ is linear and approaches $\infty$ otherwise) so there effective number of parameters is 2. Between these two extremes the effective number of parameters is not so obvious. Shedden and Zucker (2008)

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19956348

use the AIC approach to choosing smoothness and derive an approximation to the effective number of parameters under penalization - that may be useful to look at.

Comment: I think there are some typos in the display equations. Shouldn't it be $\sigma^2(t_i)$ in the denominator? And, I'm sure it's just me being slow, but I don't see how the last function could be convex in each individual $\sigma(t_i)$. Take the case $\lambda = 0$, for example. Can you explain?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which is along the line I was thinking. Two observations. First, I think Cardinal is correct: you need $\sigma^2()$ in the denominator. And Cardinal is also correct that the problem is usually non-convex. The second observation is more fundamental. What is the prior distribution associated to the penalty? If not using a bayesian rationale, Is there a different justification for this penalized likelihood?

Comment: You're right, cardinal. I was thinking about how both the penalty the normal likelihood for $\mu$ is convex. I've edited that part and fixed the typo in the display equations

Comment: @gappy, I'm sure you could cook up a prior distribution whose log is the penalty above but I don't know if it's a common one. I'm not completely sure about the rationale behind this penalty - I think it is just interpreted as a roughness penalty which imposes increasing smoothness as $\lambda$ is increased (as in the extremes pointed out above). I also know that, in the field of curve fitting, cubic splines minimize the integrated squared second derivative (the $m=2$ case) across all interpolating functions, so it is used as a roughness penalty in that setting as well.

Comment: I think that for the $m=2$ case, the (natural!) cubic smooth spline still provides the optimal answer. There is no need for the rest of the objective function to be convex in the parameters. This essentially follows from the optimal interpolation property that @Macro mentions. That said, there **is** a small potential problem here. It does not appear that the current formulation respects the nonnegativity constraint on $\sigma(t)$. In other words, the "optimal" cubic spline might go negative in places.

Comment: @cardinal - notice the "log barrier" in the objective function. This would force a strictly positive estimate of $\sigma(t)$.

Comment: @Macro: It would force nonnegativity of the individual $\sigma(t_i)$, but not necessarily for all $t$. (Unless I'm missing something.) :)